# Oozie 4.2.0 - JNI Error has occured, please check your installation

Tags: oozie, hadoop2

I have a Pseudo-distributed cluster with Oozie 4.2.0, Hadoop 2.7, Hive 1.1.2 and Java 1.8. After I built the Oozie distribution with the components I am trying to copy the "shared lib" to HDFS. When I run the command it gives me the below error. I think a JAR file is missing (or it says so).

I am not a JAVA person and have no knowledge about this error what so ever. But, I think if I have built Oozie successfully with all required JAR files then this error should not crop up. I browsed through all other similar Oozie issues with JNI error but I found no credible answer to solve this issue. Can someone help me in this front here please?

```
oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try 
again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache
/hadoop/conf/Configuration
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Comment: "I am not a JAVA person" -- then you are looking for trouble if you try to build a Hadoop component by yourself. Anyway the **Configuration** class is defined in `hadoop-common` JAR, and if that one is not in your Hadoop CLASSPATH then you probably have no CLASSPATH defined. Ugh. Good luck.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - I thought so, my best guess was "some jar missing somewhere" ! What fun would it be than building a thing and learning on your own the things you don't know! .. Thanks for you pointer, I will check my classpath in hadoop!

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - Your pointer did help me, infact the solution for this was to copy the jar files from $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/common/*.jar to the /libext in oozie folder and build the .WAR file. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution for this myself,
**Step 1** : Copy $HADOOP_INSTALL/share/common/*.jar to $OOZIE_INSTALL/libext
**Step 2** : Rebuild the .WAR file.
**Step 3** : Rerun oozie

Comment: I'm having same error when i'm running HIVE, what should i do, please help, thanks in advance :)